# Delete the text of a column that repeats in all rows (Python Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVtgZ.png)

I want to delete the text "out of 5" from the average_product_rating column for all the entries using `map` function. How should look the code i want to write?

Comment: Delete and replace for what? Or just let it emty, or null, NaN?

Answer (score 0):

According to the dataframe, actually there are kinds of ways to achieve. Here is a simple one(I suppose):

```
df['average_product_rating'] = df['average_product_rating'].str.slice_replace(start=-9, repl='')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use `map` for this. Indeed it may not be the most efficient way to replace text in a pandas column.

Try:

```
df['average_product_rating'] = df['average_product_rating'].str.replace(' out of 5', '')
```

or:

```
df['average_product_rating'] = df['average_product_rating'].str.replace(' out of 5$', '')
```

if you want to make sure the `out of 5` is at the end (notice the `$` at the end of the text to be replaced and the white at the begging).

Notice also that the generated column will be a string so you may want to convert to numeric, integer, float... use `astype` for this.